# Delete data from Elasticsearch before one month

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I would like to remove data from my Elasticsearch base, so i only got data from the past month. Is this possible in a XDELETE call or similar? Could be setup with a cronjob or similar.

Comment: If you want to perpetually keep only 1 month of data, you could also look into the TTL (time to leave) option when indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need the curator feature. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/curator-tending-your-time-series-indices/) a blog post about this and another one [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-curator-version-1-1-0-released/).
And you can find various example on the web for running it as a cron job. For example [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/curator/wiki/Logstash) or [here](http://www.ragingcomputer.com/2014/02/removing-old-records-for-logstash-elasticsearch-kibana):

```
20 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --host 127.0.0.1 -d 120 -c 90
```